# Extracting transaction data from variable length arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, data-science

I have built a small program in ruby that collects table data from my own PDF bank statements. This does so by scanning each PDF statement for tables and then filters out for transactional line item patterns.

Everything is working great and I have managed to collect an array of line items as an array of string arrays. Getting an array of keyed objects would be better but a bit tricky with the format of the statements.

The issue is that the line items have different lengths, so it's kind of tricky to always know the location of the correct values to map.

For example:

1. `["Transaction 1", "1.00"]`
2. `["Transaction 2", "Hello World", "3.00"]`
3. `["Transaction 3", "Hello World", "feeffe", "5.00"]`
4. `["Transaction 4", "Hello World", "feeffe", "5.00", "12.00"]`
5. `["Transaction 5", "Hello World @ 10.00", "feeffe", "10.00", "12.00"]`

The line items only range in between 2 and 5 array items normally.

Is there an efficient/accurate way to map the above to:

1. `{ description: "Transaction 1", amt: "1.00"}`
2. `{ description: "Transaction 2 - Hello World", amt: "3.00"}`
3. `{ description: "Transaction 3 - Hello World - feeffe", amt: "5.00"}`
4. `{ description: "Transaction 4 - Hello World - feeffe", amt: "5.00"}`
5. `{ description: "Transaction 5 - Hello World @ 10.00 - feeffe", amt: "10.00"}`

-Or is the only way to write IF conditions that looks at the array length and makes a "best guess" effort?

Comment: Do you get row array with length 4 having actual & fee value in it? Or these both value exists only in array having length 5.

Comment: You changed the question substantially since I and others posted their answers. That's a no-no at SO, for reasons that should be obvious.

Comment: I only added 2 more examples @CarySwoveland. Did not change the question.

Comment: The last element of #4 and #5 is to be disregarded. That was not the case for #1, #2 or #3. If you did not change the question why does my answer give the correct result for #1, #2 and #3, but not for #4 and #5? Why did @ray feel the need for his "update"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your transaction is on a variable `tr`, i.e.

```
 tr=["Transaction 5", "Hello World", "feeffe", "10.00", "12.00"]
```

I would first separtate this into those strings which look like an amount, and those which don't:

```
amounts,texts= tr.partition {|el| /^\d+[.]\d{2}/ =~ el}
```

Here you can check that `!amounts.empty?`, to guard agains transaction without amount. Now your hash could be

```
{
  transaction_name: texts.first,
  transaction_text: "#{texts[1]}#{amounts.size > 1 ? %( @ #{amounts.first}) : ''}#{texts.size > 2 ? %( - #{texts.last}) : ''}",
  amt: amounts.last
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for. It's dynamic and smarter than manually mapping values. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are having,

```
row = ["Transaction 2", "Hello World", "3.00"]
```

You can follow by doing,

```
{ description: row[0..-2].join(' - '), amt: row[-1] }
```

You have to further manipulate how these rows get iterated so further logic will vary.

**update:**

For condition updated specified later, it is seen to have row can have length 5 where actual amount is second last value.

```
data = (row.length == 5) ? [row[0..-3], row[-2]] : [row[0..-2], row[-1]]
{ description: data[0].join(' - '), amt: data[1] }
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my first thought as well. There are some outliers where the array ends with two array elements that are transaction values. In these cases, the second last one is the actual value and the last one is the fee value. I suppose I could do a count of each array to check and then update the index value accordingly, I was just hoping for a smarter way like some sort of regex etc.

Comment: @HermannHH Can you elaborate with example rows, so I can better look at it.

Comment: I have added example 4 & 5 to my question. These are definitely outliers, but they do appear.

Comment: @HermannHH I have updated answer. Of course you need to define boundary as I did above. Wish there can be better approach or I miss here something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
"\K[^",\]]+
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEc7Pu/1)

Comment: Thank you. This only seems to match every item in the array, so doesn't really work for this problem i.e. it doesn't distinguish between different types/lengths of line items. I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

If the number of items always determines the index of the amount element, you can do something like:

```
input = [
  ["Transaction 1", "1.00"],
  ["Transaction 2", "Hello World", "3.00"],
  ["Transaction 3", "Hello World", "feeffe", "5.00"],
  ["Transaction 4", "Hello World", "feeffe", "5.00", "12.00"],
  ["Transaction 5", "Hello World @ 10.00", "feeffe", "10.00", "12.00"]
]

ROW_LENGTH_TO_AMOUNT_INDEX = {
  2 => 1,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 3,
  5 => 3,
}


def map(transactions)
  transactions.map do |row|
    amount_index = ROW_LENGTH_TO_AMOUNT_INDEX[row.length]
    {
      description: row[0],
      amt: row[amount_index]
    }
  end
end


p map(input)

[{:description=>"Transaction 1", :amt=>"1.00"}, {:description=>"Transaction 2", :amt=>"3.00"}, {:description=>"Transaction 3", :amt=>"5.00"}, {:description=>"Transaction 4", :amt=>"5.00"}, {:description=>"Transaction 5", :amt=>"10.00"}]
```

Or, perhaps something like this?

```
MAPPERS = {
  2 => lambda { |row| { description: row[0], amt: row[1]} },
  3 => lambda { |row| { description: row[0], amt: row[2]} },
  4 => lambda { |row| { description: row[0], amt: row[3]} },
  5 => lambda { |row| { description: row[0], amt: row[3]} }
}


def map(transactions)
  transactions.map do |row|
    MAPPERS[row.length].call(row)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [["Transaction 1", "1.00"],
       ["Transaction 2", "Hello World", "3.00"],
       ["Transaction 3", "Hello World", "feeffe", "5.00"]]

arr.map {|*first, last| { description: first.join(' - '), amt: last } }
  #=> [{:description=>"Transaction 1", :amt=>"1.00"},
  #    {:description=>"Transaction 2 - Hello World", :amt=>"3.00"},
  #    {:description=>"Transaction 3 - Hello World - feeffe", :amt=>"5.00"}]
```